# What's a good way to structure questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, markdown

Is there a particular structure that would be most useful when asking a question?  I realise the type of question being asked would obviously affect this in specific cases but, in a general way, when you come to a question, what (level of) details would you like to see in what sort of order?  Are section headings useful/distracting?  How can a question be asked to make it easiest for people to answer it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I always find a question that's structured thusly is quite a good way to go:

- Preamble: What is the questioner trying to achieve, what environment are they trying to achieve it in and what isn't working
- Detail: Source-code (reduced to show the **relevant** part of the code!), screenshots, exceptions, stack-traces
- What I've tried: An outline of anything the OP has already tried

Of course this won't always be a good fit and I wouldn't suggest that a question should be broken up this way with section headings as this could make the question seem a bit stilted.

> How can a question be asked to make it easiest for people to answer it?

- By putting time and effort into composing the question
- Ensuring that the spelling & grammar doesn't detract from the content of the question
- Providing enough detail so that others stand a chance of answering the question

Answer (score 6):

Jon Skeet's [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints) is an excellent guide to asking questions. There's also a complementary post [Answering technical questions helpfully](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) which is well worth a read.

Comment: Here's a [useful post by Tom Wijsman from the SU blog as well](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/02/how-to-get-answers/)

Comment: +1 for reference to Jon Skeet's article